# heroku app not running

Tags: php, codeigniter, heroku

so I deployed my heroku app, but it says 
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments. My app is using PHP framework codeigniter to run.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

```
So I checked my logs and all over internet but couldnt find something useful.
here is my logs
    2016-02-06T23:00:43.872338+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy daf6554 by masnadhossain@live.com
2016-02-06T23:00:43.872338+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v17 created by masnadhossain@live.com
2016-02-06T23:00:43.995562+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-02-06T23:00:43.995568+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-02-06T23:00:44.023373+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-02-06T23:00:48.465994+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2`
2016-02-06T23:00:50.615984+00:00 app[web.1]: Optimizing defaults for 1X dyno...
2016-02-06T23:00:50.756965+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting php-fpm...
2016-02-06T23:00:50.749042+00:00 app[web.1]: 4 processes at 128MB memory limit.
2016-02-06T23:00:52.759245+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting httpd...
2016-02-06T23:00:53.367150+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-02-06T23:01:05.248173+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=protected-headland-51216.herokuapp.com request_id=7d0b1679-ebc3-456c-9606-40772c1c17e9 fwd="80.220.234.138" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=127ms status=404 bytes=1362
2016-02-06T23:01:05.246066+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.215.56 - - [06/Feb/2016:23:01:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 1130 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36
Nihits-MacBook-Pro:pocketAllowence nihit$
```

And one more thing I noticed is my vendor file had an error.
[image]

But I followed alot of other peoples example and put it on gitignore and tried to remove it. But nothing I do seems to work.

so here is the error 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your file path is missing a '/'.
Try changing `vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 web/` to `vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2/web/`.

File paths don't like spaces.

Comment: Where do I change it ?

Comment: it shows now 
2016-02-06T22:13:46.893256+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-02-06T22:13:51.713992+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2/web/`
2016-02-06T22:13:53.223759+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2/web/: Not a directory
2016-02-06T22:13:53.861648+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-02-06T22:13:53.819010+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 126

Comment: 2016-02-06T22:10:13.808991+00:00 app[web.1]: DOCUMENT_ROOT 'web/' does not exist

Comment: Check your Procfile.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings#setting-the-document-root

Comment: I changed my procfile to what you said, did not work

Comment: i read your article, and did it like this
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2
but it says 404 page not found

Comment: can you please check my heroku log again